# exec() is unable to encode some characters correctly when calling CMD

Tags: node.js, child-process

See my minimal example:

```
var { exec } = require('child_process'); 
var out; 
exec('echo oø', options={encoding: 'buffer'} callback=(err, stdout, stderr) => { out = stdout});
```

No matter the encoding configuration of exec options and out.toString(encoding=''), oo is passed. Evidently when using 'buffer' encoding in exec, i get:

```
out:
    <Buffer 6f 6f 0d 0a>
out.toString(): 
    ‘oo\r\n’
```

Any ideas how to get exec to return "oø" when calling "echo oø"?

Comment: first, your code is not really a valid JS piece of code. second, this code seems to work fine for me. could you clarify what's wrong? and provide actual runnable code

Comment: "Your code is not valid JS." ... "Code work fine for me." ... Provide actual runnable code. - What are you saying here?

Comment: the piece of code you shared is a mix of valid JS code with documentation, it's not exactly something you can copy paste and run. Adapting it to atual code, it works as it is supposed.